# Check for Returned Rows Using PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I have the following code, it is indicating that there are 0 rows returned but the data should be returning several rows, what is wrong with it?

```
$sql2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tips` WHERE tips = `$tips`");

if ($sql2->rowCount() > 0) {

} else {

}
```

In other words `rowCount` is always 0 but there is data in the database.

I'm not getting any errors etc.

Comment: You need to execute the query first. And when you use a prepared statement you should use placeholders for your values and bind these to the values when you execute the statement.

Comment: `\`$tips\`` or `'$tips'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the rowCount you need to execute the query beforehand, so do:

```
$sql2=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tips` WHERE tips = '$tips'");
$sql2->execute();
if ($sql2->rowCount() > 0){

}else{

}
```

Link to the [manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) that has somw useful examples.

---

By the way, i advise you to use make the best use of PDO:

```
$sql2=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tips` WHERE tips = :tips");
$sql2->bindParam(':tips', $tips, PDO::PARAM_INT); // or PDO::PARAM_STR
$sql2->execute();
if ($sql2->rowCount() > 0){

}else{

}
```

Comment: Alternatively (since it's a very simple query and no need to bindParam): `$sql2->execute([':tips' => $tips])` or replace ":tips" with "?" and `$sql2->execute([$tips])`

Comment: @noahnu bindparam is not for simple or not simple queries. It is for preventing Sql injections. It is used to sanitize the parameters passed to the query if they come from user inputs. So even for a "simple" query it can be really usefull!

Comment: @LelioFaieta It is still a prepared statement with bound parameters, it is just that the binding is easier as you can send an array to the `execute()` method. By the way, you can still used named parameters...

Comment: I suppose the one issue with `execute[params here]` would be relying on implicit casting since it "defaults" to `PDO::PARAM_STR`. Also, by "simple" I was referring to readability in using `execute` without named parameters. I'd recommend named parameters if the query has multiple parameters (prevent mistakes due to ordering, etc...).

Comment: BTW it worth mention that the original form could not work at all, because of the backticks in _WHERE tips = `$tips`_: should be _WHERE tips = '$tips'_ instead.